# MSWord If Statement Syntax

Tags: ms-word

```
Column A = qty
Column F = Unit Price
Column G = Total Amount
```

Cell G7 contains =A7*F7.  This formula works fine.  However, if you copy the formula down, then you get $0.00 on lines that have no data.  I tried putting in IF(A7>0,A7*F7).  It returns nothing even if there is information in Cell A7 and Cell F7.  Can someone help me with the correct syntax to get the value when needed and have the cell be blank when there is no item?

Comment: Are you trying on excel?

Comment: No, I'm working in a MSWord document.  Apparently, it was one set up by our vendor and it is full of errors.  I have fixed some of the other issues, this is the last one.  It's an MSWord Invoice.

Comment: Have you tried: `=IF(A7="","",A7*F7)` ?

Comment: @BonnieSterling: As assylias said, this formula should work. If not, can you show screenshot?

Comment: Just tried, didn't work.  Thanks, assylias.

Comment: I'm new here.  How do I post a screenshot?

Comment: @BonnieSterling: take a screenshot and save it as `.jpg`. Edit the question, Click on Image icon that is after flower braces and browse the image, click upload.

Comment: As a new user, it won't allow me to post an image.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  We ended up creating a field in sql and replacing the formula with the field.